# Using / Setting up fingerprint sensor on a Lenovo B40-70 laptop

Tags: 12.04, lenovo, fingerprint-reader

Does anyone know how to use the fingerprint scanner of the Lenovo B40-70 laptop with Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: i tried many things like fingerprint print gui but it do not detects the finger print reader really lenovo sucks i regret buying lenovo for ubuntu

Comment: I got mine from the company, it seems its better suited to run windows.
Except for the finger sensor the lenovo runs okay. I also have a problem with the USB ports at times.

Answer (score 4):

The fingerprint reader works fine for Lenovo B40. You have to do some extra configuration.

Check if the fingerprint reader is detected.

```
lsusb
```

If its present, install fprint

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fprint
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpam-fprintd
```

Ensure that a line similar to `auth [success=2 default=ignore] pam_fprintd.so` is present `in common-auth` by

```
grep fprint /etc/pam.d/common-auth
```

Use the below command to enroll the fingerprint

```
fprintd-enroll
```

To test whether the enroll worked completely, try the following command on **new terminal window**.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Reference**

[**Easy steps to enable Finger Print Reader on Linux Mint / Ubuntu**](http://tryitnw.blogspot.in/2013/02/easy-steps-to-enable-finger-print.html)

Comment: Included the essential part.